# Save/restore git/cvs checkout changes when switching branches?

Tags: git, cvs, branch, rcs

Using cvs, git or another technique (file system level?), I would like to:

1. Make modifications on branch A
2. Checkout branch B: Changes to branch A are "stowed away" (by name would be nice), branch B is checked out such that my branch A changes are gone
3. Make modifications on branch B
4. Checkout branch A: Changes to branch B are "stowed away" (by name would be nice), branch A is checked out such that my branch B changes are gone but now my "saved" branch A changes from Step #2 are back

Git-stash does not appear to fit the flow I'm describing although my impression could be wrong.

Techniques involving RCS's or file system or command-line tools or otherwise are welcome.

Comment: Is this not a standard branching/merging workflow?  Commit changes to A, checkout on B, commit changes on B, check back out on A.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git stash is the tool you are looking for

```
# hack on A
git stash

git checkout B
# hack on B
git stash

git checkout A
git stash list # this is only to check which stash you want to pop
git stash pop stash@{1}
```

this should work

Comment: Ah, my impression definitely was wrong! Thank you for the very helpful little tutorial.

Comment: You can also stash a name/message with your content using `git stash save 'Changes made before switching branches or whatever'`. I find that helpful most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

How does git-stash not fit your workflow, beyond not happening automatically?  This sounds like *exactly* what git-stash is for.

http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html

Comment: I guess I was wrong git-stash definitely does seem to be what I want. A little too manual but perhaps I could script something around it.

Comment: I would be completely lost without git-stash, I think.